# Angular project working on localhost but not on GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, typescript, github-pages

I am making a todo list in Angular that also saves and restores on refresh, and on localhost I can add to the list
and the item displays below the add button. On GitHub Pages, when I click add it does nothing.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jusmccar/TodoList)

[GitHub Pages](https://jusmccar.github.io/TodoList/)

This is the error I am getting from the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')
    at e.addTodo (main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:139904)
    at main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:140617
    at Qh (main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:60440)
    at i (main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:60625)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:107043)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.a66b249bad4eb06b.js:1:7168)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2beb7ccacdd609b1.js:1:82284)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.a66b249bad4eb06b.js:1:7089)
    at M.runTask (polyfills.a66b249bad4eb06b.js:1:2563)
    at m.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.a66b249bad4eb06b.js:1:8219)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### The Problem

The problem is not from GitHub Pages. It is from the Angular code itself.

The code works well except for one thing. On a first-time visit of the Angular application in a browser, the `todos` key has never been set before in `localStorage` in that domain (GitHub Pages or localhost). So the `getTodos()` function returns null thus making the  `this.todos` initializing statement in `ngOnInit()` to be set to null.

##### Solution

To solve the problem, add the if-null operator (`??`) to the return of `getTodos()` to include an empty array (`[]`). That way, if it is a first-time visit, or if the user played around and cleared `localStorage`, the app should still work (given that new todos will be pushed to an empty array).

So change [line 59 of `todos.component.ts`](https://github.com/jusmccar/TodoList/blob/9a9aae66001d829905ea4f37ed4cd3fa0be5d654/src/app/components/todos/todos.component.ts#L59) from

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")!);
```

to

```
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")!) ?? [];
```

Comment: Thank you! I took it one step further and removed all definite assignment assertions from my project.

Comment: You are welcome. As for the definite assertions (!), yes it was unnecessary in most cases in the code. However, in itself, the assertion is good.  A good place to use is when you have defined a component class member with @ViewChild (with #selector in the HTML template). You have to add the non-null checker to tell TypeScript you are sure that that variable will have a value.